# Customize alertdialog android api 10

Tags: java, android, styles, android-alertdialog

I would like to know how to customize theme/style of `AlertDialog` using `sdk api 10`. I know how to do that from 11 onwards but not how to do it on the 10.

**XML Layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    style="@style/dialog_theme" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/disclaimerText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/disclaimer"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkDisclaimer"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/agree" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**JAVA Resource file**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//Setting Dialog Title
builder.setTitle("Disclaimer");
//Setting Dialog Message
builder.setMessage(R.string.disclaimer);
View view = (View) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_disclaimer, null);
builder.setView(view);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
View myView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.customize_dialog, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(myView);
builder.setTitle("Customize dialog");
builder.setCancelable(false);
AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
alert.show();
```

You have to create a layout in res/layout/ called customize_dialog.xml, 
you can also add to "myView" other view object.

To add tipical Alert button:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        //action to do
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});


builder.setNegativeButton("Close",new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        //action to do
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I have already created a custom layout and I added to the dialog but the issue continues to be different, in my layout I added style = "@ style / dialog_theme" but no, I still see the layout of the system. I have edited my answer